# How can I set a breakpoint on a Julia library function?

Tags: debugging, julia

I am a newbie to Julia, so I expect I either overlooked something or there is a fundamental reason why this can't be done. Briefly, I have some code that triggers an exception in the LinearAlgebra package when I call it with a `Float32` array, but not with a `Float16` array. From the stack trace, I know exactly where in LinearAlgebra the exception occurs, and in VS Code I have set a breakpoint on that specific line. Yet, when I run the code in the debugger, the breakpoint is not triggered and my code hits the exception. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to set a breakpoint on a Julia library function?

The code that I'm trying to debug is the following (requires Apple Metal). It triggers an exception inside lapack.jl when trying to take a pointer to a GPU array.

```
using Metal
using KernelAbstractions
using LinearAlgebra

backend = MetalBackend()
A = KernelAbstractions.allocate(backend, Float32, 3, 3)
qr!(A)
```

I set a breakpoint on line 457 of lapack.jl (the `ccall` that calls into Metal.jl), if that is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out lapack.jl was being treated as compiled code to speed up debugging. Removing LinearAlgebra from the list of compiled packages in the debugger solved the issue.

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot or one sentence of explanation for "Removing LinearAlgebra from the list of compiled packages in the debugger". This will make this answer much more useful for others.